# How should I write tests for Forms in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'd like to simulate requests to my views in Django when I'm writing tests. This is mainly to test the forms. Here's a snippet of a simple test request:

```
from django.tests import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_forms(self):
        response = self.client.post("/my/form/", {'something':'something'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200) # we get our page back with an error
```

The page always returns a response of 200 whether there's an form error or not. How can I check that my Form failed and that the particular field (`soemthing`) had an error?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

I think if you just want to test the form, then you should just test the form and not the view where the form is rendered. Example to get an idea:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.forms import MyForm

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_forms(self):
        form_data = {'something': 'something'}
        form = MyForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
        ... # other tests relating forms, for example checking the form data
```

Comment: +1. The idea of **unit** tests is to test each unit separately.

Comment: @Daniel But integration tests are way more useful and more likely to catch bugs.

Comment: @wobbily_col It also takes more time to spot what is the actual bug in an integration test. In a unit test its more obvious. I think for a good test coverage you need anyway both of them though.

Comment: @Danbiel Sure. I think they are a good fit for certain units of functionality, but a lot of the time people just seem to test the framework / library they are using. In general I would say integration tests are more valuable.

Comment: This is how you check for a specific form error: ```self.assertEquals(form.errors['recipient'], [u"That recipient isn't valid"])```

Comment: `self.assertEqual(form.is_valid(), True)` could be simplified: `self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())`

Comment: I like doing `self.assertTrue(form.isVald(), form.errors)` - that ensures that the test failure message includes the reasons why the form failed to validate.

Answer (score 87):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFormError

```
from django.tests import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_forms(self):
        response = self.client.post("/my/form/", {'something':'something'})
        self.assertFormError(response, 'form', 'something', 'This field is required.')
```

Where "form" is the context variable name for your form, "something" is the field name, and "This field is required." is the exact text of the expected validation error.

Comment: This raises an AttibuteError for me:
AttributeError: 'SafeUnicode' object has no attribute 'errors'

Comment: for newbie users: create a user beforehand and use `self.client.force_login(self.user)` as first line in the test method.

Comment: I had an issue with this post(), then I figured out that I had to send it as multipart as following

response = self.client.post("/form-url/", data={
            'name': 'test123',
            'category': 1,
            'note': 'note123'
        }, content_type=django.test.client.MULTIPART_CONTENT)

If any stuck with getting empty instance when saving the form, then check the requests sent from browser

Comment: The signature of this method [changed in Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFormError) - calling it with the `response` argument is deprecated and will fail in Django 5.0.

Answer (score 19):

The original 2011 answer was

```
self.assertContains(response, "Invalid message here", 1, 200)
```

But I see now (2018) [there is a whole crowd of applicable asserts available](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#assertions):

- assertRaisesMessage
- assertFieldOutput
- assertFormError
- assertFormsetError

Take your pick.