# Django - Taking values from POST

Tags: django

I'm passing some data to my template ("appointments.html") which looks like this:

Appointments today

Appointment ID : 84218332 Scheduled Time: 2019-10-18T01:00:00

- Arrived

Appointment ID : 84218332 Scheduled Time: 2019-10-18T22:05:00

- Arrived

```
<h1>Appointments today</h1>
    {% for p in appointment %}
        <tr>
            <td>Appointment ID : {{ p.patient }} Scheduled Time: {{p.scheduled_time}}</td>
            <td>
            <form action="{{ p.id }}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" name="appid" value="{{ p.id }}">
              <input type="submit" value="Arrived" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
            </td>

          </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I want to call another view in views.py by clicking on "Arrived" button which gets back the p.id which is passed as a value to further use it for other purposes.

urls.py :

```
url(r'^appointment/<int:appid>/$', views.arrived, name='arrived')
```

views.py

```
def arrived(request, appid):
        if request.method == 'POST':

            print(appid)
```

ERROR :

```
Using the URLconf defined in drchrono.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^setup/$ [name='setup']
^welcome/$ [name='welcome']
^appointment/$ [name='appointment']
^appointment/<int:appid>/$ [name='arrived']
^schedule/$ [name='schedule']
^patient_checkin/$ [name='checkin']
^update_info/$ [name='update']
^admin/
^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='begin']
^complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='complete']
^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='disconnect']
^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/(?P<association_id>\d+)/$ [name='disconnect_individual']
The current path, appointment/131848814, didn't match any of these.
```

How do I fix this and what am I missing exactly?

EDIT: Changed my approach. Thought this is easier.

Comment: just a guess, but `<form action="arrived" method="post">` -> `<form action="arrived/" method="post">`, or even `accounts/arrived/`.

Comment: I had tried that, it doesnt work. @monkut

Comment: Show more of your error, I suspect this is your console output of the dev server, show the full traceback including the call.   The problem appears to be that your not hitting your `arrived` view.

Comment: @monkut please check the edit, this is simpler and I guess I am missing something simple now.

Comment: I suggest you write a testcase to cover this.  This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304248/how-should-i-write-tests-for-forms-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up the old url and the new path syntaxes. Your URL should either be:

```
path('appointment/<int:appid>/', views.arrived, name='arrived')
```

or

```
url(r'^appointment/(?P<appid>\d+)/$', views.arrived, name='arrived')
```

Also, as Dipen noted in their answer, you should change the form action to `{% url 'arrived' p.id %}`.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as accepted. Although, @Dipen Dadhaniya your suggestion was important too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [URL template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Change:

```
<form action="{{ p.id }}" method="post">
```

To:

```
<form action="{% url 'arrived' p.id %}" method="post">
```